# Bad request uploading photo to PicasaWeb from GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk, gdata, picasa

I am working on a webapp on Google App Engine with an upload feature on PicasaWeb.
I use this code to upload the photo:

```
myService = new PicasawebService("my-picasa-web-service");
myService.setConnectTimeout(60000);
myService.setReadTimeout(60000);
myService.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
PhotoEntry myPhoto = new PhotoEntry();
myPhoto.setClient("myAdminClient");
MediaStreamSource myMedia = new MediaStreamSource(stream, "image/jpeg");
myPhoto.setMediaSource(myMedia);
PhotoEntry returnedPhoto = myService.insert(new URL(albumFeedUrl), myPhoto);
```

where ***stream*** variable is an InputStream with the uploaded file.

This code works if I run it in a standalone client program.
But when I run it using GAE th last line raise and exception and I can see this in the log:

```
com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: OK
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
<H2>Error 400</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:602)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.insert(MediaService.java:400)
```

Can you help me to fix this error?

How could I get more information about this?

Thanks
stefano

Comment: no idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue; it was related to a content type not valid I was using.
In my exaqmple I reported "image/jpeg" as parameter of "new MediaStreamSource()" method. In my original code I was using a variable as content type and it was setted in a bad way, for this reason I had the error.